# How is this stack trace possible in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, stack-trace

My problem is some code that is getting called in a reentrant way which is causing it to crash and trying to debug how it can possibly be called by 2 threads or reentrant with the same thread.  I added a log that gives the Environment.StackTrace and this is what it got at the end of this message.

My confusion is after the line:

```
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Those seem like the top or beginning of any stack.  But notice that the stack trace actually begins before those lines. In fact, line previous to those above is this:

```
at TickZoom.MBTFIX.MBTFIXSimulator.OnTick(Message quoteMessage, SymbolInfo symbol, Tick tick) in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Public\Providers\MBTFIX\MBTFIXProvider\MBTFIX\MBTFIXSimulator.cs:line 481
```

Here's the line 481:

```
if( trace) log.Trace("Sending tick: " + tick);
```

But that line is just a log message and can't in any possible way call System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart().   So how does this crazy stack trace exist?

```
at TickZoom.MBTFIX.MBTFIXSimulator.OnTick(Message quoteMessage, SymbolInfo symbol, Tick tick) in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Public\Providers\MBTFIX\MBTFIXProvider\MBTFIX\MBTFIXSimulator.cs:line 479
at TickZoom.FIX.FIXServerSymbolHandler.ProcessOnTickCallBack() in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Public\Providers\Common\ProviderUtil\FIX\FIXServerSymbolHandler.cs:line 301
at TickZoom.Threading.TaskLoop.Run() in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Engine\Parallel\TaskBase.cs:line 669
at TickZoom.Threading.TaskBase.Execute(ThreadInfo thread) in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Engine\Parallel\TaskBase.cs:line 213
at TickZoom.Threading.ParallelManager.ExecuteTasks(ThreadInfo thread) in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Engine\Parallel\ParallelManager.cs:line 685
at TickZoom.Threading.ParallelManager.Run() in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Engine\Parallel\ParallelManager.cs:line 632
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
at TickZoom.MBTFIX.MBTFIXSimulator.OnTick(Message quoteMessage, SymbolInfo symbol, Tick tick) in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Public\Providers\MBTFIX\MBTFIXProvider\MBTFIX\MBTFIXSimulator.cs:line 481
at TickZoom.FIX.FIXServerSymbolHandler.ProcessOnTickCallBack() in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Public\Providers\Common\ProviderUtil\FIX\FIXServerSymbolHandler.cs:line 301
at TickZoom.Threading.TaskLoop.Run() in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Engine\Parallel\TaskBase.cs:line 669
at TickZoom.Threading.TaskBase.Execute(ThreadInfo thread) in C:\Local\TickZoom\Project\Engine\Parallel\TaskBase.cs:line 213
```

Comment: Thanks...I edited it to add that line right after the copy of it in the text above...hope you have some idea...never seen anything so weird in 20+ years of programming (since I started programming as a little kid).

Comment: That is _thoroughly_ weird.  What's `log`?  Can this be reproduced?

Comment: When having strange reentrancy issues the usual suspect is that the windows message loop get pumped somehow. I would read the disassembled code to try to figure out how exactly the callstack ended up in ThreadStart again.

Comment: Sorry...found that problem was because in throwing the exception it included a stack trace with Environment.StackTrace as part of the message and then it was followed by the stack trace produced by the exception.  That's the cause of the weird stack trace output.  As for the reentrant problem, that was easy to solve after getting past this GOOF! Sorry and thanks for your time!!!

Comment: @Wayne, you should answer your own question then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the comments to your question, weird stack traces such as this arise when one or more stack traces are output right after one another:

```
Log.WriteLine(Environment.StackTrace)
try
{
    SomethingThatThrowsAnException();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); // better to do Log.WriteLine(e) to get the message
}
```